# What does "n.x" stand for in books?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

[image: a book images]

I know in books, "p. 12" means page 12, but what is meant by "n. 9"?

Comment: Possibly (foot/end)note. Although it would help to know what book EVANS is, as specialist publications may have other abbreviations. Also, what citation style is being used - [MLA](https://style.mla.org/how-do-i-cite-a-numbered-footnote/) cites footnotes slightly differently as e.g. 12n9?

Comment: You could look in _The Varieties of Reference_ by Gareth Evans (1982) on page 12, and see if there are at least 9 notes, or references to notes, and then see what the one marked '9' looks like...

Comment: Please don't add 'solved', Reddit style. A question needs an accepted answer to be considered 'solved'. I've rolled back the edit.

Comment: I don't even see n.x in the image. N means número. Probably a list of **points** on the page.

Comment: This book isn't in English. Why are you asking here?

Answer (score 1):

It means note 9...

Assuming this does refer to Gareth Evans *The variety of Reference* we find at the bottom of page 12:

[image]

> ...
> <sup>9</sup>*Posthumous Writings* p.174. I am accepting the dating of this passage, by the editors of the *Nachlass*, as contemporary with the dialogue with Pünjer, though my case would be much strengthened if the dating, by Scholz, of around 1906 could be substantiated.

That is the date of "1884" is derived from Evans, who has got it from the editors of the unpublished works of Frege, although Evans expresses his doubt.

Comment: It could be note but it isn't in your snippet.

Comment: It totally is the snippet  It is saying see the note 9 on that page to understand the context for dating to 1884

Comment: I cannot see N. in your snippet.

Comment: @Lambie - _Nota_ in Portuguese starts with an N. It's clearly a convention.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why don't you tell that to James? It is not in his snippet.

Comment: I think you miss the point here,  The reason I've included the snippet is so that you can see that this note is relevant to the text in the question, from which you may infer that this is indeed the content that the original citation is referring to.  And since page 12, note 9 is relevant one can suppose that p.12 n.9 means exactly that.  Thus "n.9" must mean note 9.

Comment: @JamesK - exactly. As 'n' is clearly an abbreviation for _nota_ and there is a note numbered 9, there was no need for you to show a snippet with an actual 'N' or 'n' in it, which you would be unlikely to be able to find in any case. In books, academic or otherwise, referenced elsewhere or not, you don't see a 'P' in front of each page's number either.